# RxJS Map 2 arrays into one and add a property. Which operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

From the backend I receive

```
{ 
 top10: [{ amount: 5634, items: { code: "NIK", description: "NIKE" }}... x10]
 brands: [ { amount: 6564, items: { code: "ADD", description: "ADDIDAS" }}...x169]
}
```

The brands in the top 10 are also in the brands array. So brands array contains all, top10 is only the 10 most popular.

I need to return a single array which looks like this.

```
[{amount: 6564, items: { code: "ADD", description: "ADDIDAS", group: "Top10"},
{amount: 3362, items: { code: "PUM", description: "PUMA", group: "Top10"}...rest of top 10, 
{amount: 6564, items: { code: "ADD", description: "ADDIDAS", group: "allbrands"}, 
{amount: 3362, items: { code: "PUM", description: "PUMA", group: "allbrands"}... rest of brands]
```

So I need to map through the first array and append an extra property called group and give it a value of "Top10" then map through the second array and append the group property and give it the value "allbrands" and emit everything as a single array.

I am looking at piping the response through flatmap/mergemap but I'm not sure if that is their correct use in this instance.

I need the correct version of the below.

```
this.http.get(`${mainURL)`).pipe(flatMap( item => { // iterate over item and 
     append group to each item with name of array
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` is a higher order mapping operator that is used to map from one observable to another. You'd need to use `map` operator in your case. You'd also need to use `Array#map` with spread operator to combine the arrays and introduce a new property to each object of the array.

```js
this.http.get(`${mainURL}`).pipe(
  map((brands: any) => {
    const top10WGroups = brands.top10.map(brand => ({...brand, group: "Top10"}));
    const allWGroups = brands.brands.map(brand => ({...brand, group: "allbrands"}));
    return [ ...top10WGroups, ...allWGroups ];
  }
)
```

Comment: it should return an array so last statement should be [ ..., ... ]

Comment: @Ritesh: Yes I've already updated the answer.